# Jquery - How to remove text after link inside last item in list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help with removing text with Jquery after link inside last item in list. Thank you for your help.

HTML:

```
<ul id="mylinks" style="text-align: left; margin-left: -25px;">
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li>
    <li class="small" style="display: inline;"><a href="#">Text</a>|</li> {* | to remove *}
</ul>
```

Comment: _after link or inside link ??????????_

Comment: You can not't have text there. It will be invalid HTML

Comment: Sorrz guys i forgot copy text after link

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? The StackOverflow community would generally expect a question to show some research effort: please post the code you've already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to remove is a text node not an element, so please use `.contents()`
Try,

```
$('#mylinks').contents().last().remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb5MR/1/)

According to your new requirement you can try,

```
$('#mylinks li:last').contents().last().remove();
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb5MR/2/)

Comment: Pease look now on mz code i edited my post I forgot to copy | after link

Comment: @user3342042 see my new edit..

Comment: Your code will remove also elements which are not text as the OP wanted http://jsfiddle.net/Tb5MR/4/ . look at my solution to check also for nodeType

Answer (score 2):

Here, how about taking a substring of the existing HTML, assuming of course there is only 1 character you wish to remove from the end (`|`):

```
$('#mylinks li').html(function(_,v){
   return v.substr(0,v.length-1);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kZDTW/1/)

Comment: +1 you understood the OP perfectly.

Comment: Only after they made the update, was confusing to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

> Use last-child in Jquery

```
$("#mylinks li:last-child a").text("");
```

Comment: @oGeez - that is not a question.Removing text with Jquery after link inside last item in list.please read a question and put downvote

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#mylinks li:last').contents() .filter(function(i,n) {
       return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== ''  ;
   }).remove()
```

This is will *test* if it's actually literal text .

http://jsfiddle.net/Tb5MR/3/